# MoviePy/ffmpeg Progress Bar in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ffmpeg, moviepy

MoviePy has a text-based progress indicator in my Sublime Text console. It looks like this:

```
  0%|          | 0/121 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  4%|4         | 5/121 [00:00<00:02, 42.43it/s]
  8%|8         | 10/121 [00:00<00:02, 43.69it/s]
 12%|#2        | 15/121 [00:00<00:02, 43.52it/s]
 17%|#6        | 20/121 [00:00<00:02, 43.78it/s]
```

I want to pipe that progress to a text widget that I made in TKinter. I figured out how to send stdout to the textwidget, but these progress updates stay in Sublime.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the source code for printing these things (uses the submodule tqdm btw), and try a find a way to put it back to your code? Let us know if you found a solution!

Comment: Hey, looking to do the exact same thing. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: This is now possible, but there is no documentation for it. See https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1020

Answer (score 0):

you should check in stderr instead of stdout

here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722306/5862335), just keep it in mind that you should replace the line `sys.stdout = pl` to `sys.stderr = pl`

also insert a `delete` call befor the line `self.textbox.insert(tk.END, text)` would be nice