# How to get python console logs on my tkinter window instead of a CMD window while executing an exe file created using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

## Problem statement

I have created a `python 3.6` script that performs some data conversion and uses `tkinter` for GUI (folder selection and other options).

I have converted this to an `exe` file using `pyinstaller` & would like other users (who don't have python installed) to be able to use the tool.

However, when I open the `exe`, it opens a `CMD window` which shows the logs usually shown on the `python console`.

I'd like to get this redirected to a `text box` or `frame` in my `tkinter` window itself - instead of opening a new CMD window when clicked.

## Sample code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def browse():
    directory=fd.askdirectory()
    print ('The selected  directory is: ', directory)

def convert():
    # perform file manipulation
    print ("Files converted")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title")
label=tk.Label(window,text="Instructions")
label.pack()
browseButton=tk.Button(window,text="Browse Folder", command=browse)
browseButton.pack(pady=10)
runButton=tk.Button(window,text="Convert files", command=convert)
runButton.pack(pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

**Then I convert the file to `exe` using `pyinstaller`**

```
> pyinstaller --onefile TkinterGUI_test.py
```

## Expected result

[image]

I have seen numerous posts on stackoverflow which are related but don't match my requirements. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, you're printing your statements, you'd have to create `tk.labels` instead or something

Comment: @Max, Thanks for your response. That sounds a little too messy if I have to convert all my prints to a tk.label - will try though. 

What about other object such as a matplotlib plot?

Comment: Matplotlib plot will be even more messy, thats a whole other module! Label will just add the text inside the tkinter window; not messy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to hide the console you need to add the `--noconsole` to your pyinstaller command.

in order to redirect your printed output you could use something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class PrintLogger(): # create file like object
    def __init__(self, textbox): # pass reference to text widget
        self.textbox = textbox # keep ref

    def write(self, text):
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, text) # write text to textbox
            # could also scroll to end of textbox here to make sure always visible

    def flush(self): # needed for file like object
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def do_something():
        print('i did something')
        root.after(1000, do_something)

    root = tk.Tk()
    t = tk.Text()
    t.pack()
    # create instance of file like object
    pl = PrintLogger(t)

    # replace sys.stdout with our object
    sys.stdout = pl

    root.after(1000, do_something)
    root.mainloop()
```

because the print statement directs its output at sys.stdout by replacing the output we get exactly the same in the textbox, this means that `print` inserts newlines and anything else it would normally do in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks @James,  the '--noconsole' works great! I'll try using your redirect script and let you know if it works too. :)

Comment: so with this all I need to do it redirect my print statements to the Printlogger? Will it also support .format options in some way?

Comment: if the print statement supports it then this will support it as it catches the output from print not the inner workings.

Comment: not a problem. note you could redirect stderr in the same way if desired to show exception text, however you would still have to trap the exceptions to stop python from exiting when they happen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What if I wish to include a matplotlib plot into the textbox as well?

Comment: matplotlib is an entirely different question, and while you can embed matplotlib into tk the Text widget cannot, the best you could do is overlay the plot on top of the text.

Comment: The text widget allows plotting of images, so if I save the plots as an image first and then try to plot the image, will it work or should I use that approach?

Comment: @ParvBanks I stand corrected, you could do this without saving the images by using the tk backend to matplotlib, getting a handle to the tk canvas and using `test.window_create` to embed it. but that is a different question. try it, if you have difficulty post another question and you will get help there

Comment: thank you! Sorry for pestering .. you've been great help :) 

Will do when I get there.. just wanted to know if it's possible :P

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't capture and process ANSI escape sequences in the stdout stream. I've created a rudimentary tk app (on my github page) that connects to a serial port and captures enough ANSI escape sequences to allow moving the cursor and deleting and backspacing as well as scroll past commands. later i intend to expand it for colors and support stdout/stderr. I wish there were a finished package somewhere.